# How to finish a specific intent under different method

Tags: java, android

So I have two methods. The intent works as a "Night mode" filter for screen. It is called out when button is pressed in 1 method. But I can't figure out how can I finish the intent under the other method when the off button is clicked. Any help is appriciated! I wanna finish the overlay intent which acts as a filter under the "turnNightOff" method.
Heres the code:

```
private void turnNightOn() {    
    try {
        modeOnOffButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.nightmodeonbutton);
        Intent filter = new Intent(this,NightmodeFilter.class);                
        startActivity(filter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void turnNightOff() {
    try {            
        modeOnOffButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.nightmodeonoffbutton);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're starting 5 activities?  That's absolutely not what you want to do.  You need to back up a step, explain what your real feature is, and come up with a different way to do it.

Comment: That is just the "blackness" level i want to reach, calling activity 5 times gives the result needed. But i guess i can change it, but even if i called it one time, i still dont know how to finish the activity under the NightOff method.

Comment: You probably don't want to be calling any activities.  Not if you want buttons in this activity to still work.  Starting an activity is like going to a new webpage-  you can't interact with the old ones til you hit the back button

Comment: I am using a transparent activity on normal acivity with black transparent color for the "Night mode" filter effect.

Comment: That's not the right way to do it, at all.  Scrap this implementation and start over.  Transparent activites do not allow you to interact with the previous activity, and will screw up your backstack.  Nor would it be persistent if you went to another activity via normal navigation